# Gas Estimate of function: Infinite

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

Here's my first ever smart contract. What exactly causes such a warning and how should I improve my code?

This is just one of many similar warnings

> Warning:
> Gas requirement of function Consensus.deployPmu(string) high: infinite. If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

contract Consensus {
    
    struct PMU{
        string name;
        address pmu;
        uint256[] data;
        bool errorFlag;
        uint256 errorCount;
    }
    
    mapping (address => PMU) PMUS;
    
   address[]  accounts;
    uint256[] empty;
    function deployPmu(string memory _name) public{
        
        PMUS[msg.sender] = PMU(_name,msg.sender,empty,false,0);
        accounts.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function print() public view returns(string memory name, uint256[] memory data,bool errorFlag,uint256 errorCount){
        PMU memory instancePMU = PMUS[msg.sender];
        return (instancePMU.name,instancePMU.data,instancePMU.errorFlag,instancePMU.errorCount);
    }
    
    function log(uint256[] memory roc) public{
        for (uint i=0; i<roc.length;i++){
            PMUS[msg.sender].data.push(roc[i]);
            
            if(roc[i]<12){
                PMUS[msg.sender].errorFlag = false;
                errorFlags[msg.sender] = false;
                PMUS[msg.sender].errorCount=0;
            }
        
            if(roc[i]>12){
                PMUS[msg.sender].errorCount= PMUS[msg.sender].errorCount+1;
            }

            if( PMUS[msg.sender].errorCount >= 5){
                
                PMUS[msg.sender].errorFlag = true;
                errorFlags[msg.sender] = true;
                PMUS[msg.sender].errorCount = 0;
            }
        }
           
    }
    
    
    mapping (address => bool) errorFlags;
    bool GridFault=false;
    bool PMUfault=false;
    
    address[] tru;
    address[] falz;
    
    function faultStatus () public returns (address[] memory)
    {   
        address[] memory empty;
        tru = empty;
        falz =empty;
        GridFault = false;
        PMUfault = false;
        
            uint256 count =0;
            for(uint256 i =0; i<accounts.length; i++){
                if(errorFlags[accounts[i]] == true){
                    count = count + 1;
                    tru.push(accounts[i]);
                }
                else{
                    falz.push(accounts[i]);
                }
                
            }
            
            if(count > (accounts.length-1)/2){
                GridFault = true;
                if(falz.length != 0){
                    PMUfault = true;
                    
                }    
            }
            else if(count == 0){
                GridFault = false;
                PMUfault = false;
            }
            else{
                PMUfault = true;
                return tru;
            }

    }
    
    function gridstatus() public view returns(address[] memory, bool, bool){
        
        if(GridFault == true){ 
            return (falz,GridFault, PMUfault);
        }
        else{
            return(tru,GridFault, PMUfault);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will limiting the number of the PMUs that can be deployed so that its no longer a dynamic array help with this error?

Comment: As the message says - `this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage` (you are copying).